# Getting the singular values of np.linalg.svd as a matrix

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

Given a 5x4 matrix A =

[image]

A piece of python code to construct the matrix

```
A = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 4],
              [0, 3, 0, 0],
              [0, 0, 0, 0],
              [2, 0, 0, 0]])
```

[wolframalpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=svd%20%7B%7B1,%200,%200,%200%7D,%7B0,%200,%200,%204%7D,%7B0,%203,%200,%200%7D,%7B0,%200,%200,%200%7D,%7B2,%200,%200,%200%7D%7D) gives the svd result

[image]

the Vector(s) with the singular values Σ is in this form

[image]

the equivalent quantity (NumPy call it s) in the output of `np.linalg.svd` is in this form

```
[ 4.          3.          2.23606798 -0.        ]
```

is there a way to have the quantity in output of numpy.linalg.svd shown as wolframalpha?

Comment: I edited your question title - Sigma is the singular values themselves, not the vectors with the singular values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get most of the way there with `diag`:

```py
>>> u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(a)
>>> np.diag(s)
array([[ 4.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  3.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  2.23606798,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , -0.        ]])
```

Note that wolfram alpha is giving an extra row. Getting that is marginally more involved:

```
>>> sigma = np.zeros(A.shape, s.dtype)
>>> np.fill_diagonal(sigma, s)
>>> sigma
array([[ 4.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  3.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  2.23606798,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        , -0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Depending on what your goal is, removing a column from U might be a better approach than adding a row of zeros to sigma. That would look like:

```
>>> u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(a, full_matrices=False)
```