# is it an appropriate way to compute eigendecomposition by using this command `np.linalg.eig(H*H)`?

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I am learning this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56728513/10731613) and this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1417968/673047).

I am trying to reproduce the computation as this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1417968/673047) with Python, NumPy.

```
H = np.array([[0.1, 0.3, .4],[0.5 , 0.5, 0.9],[0.1, 0.4, 0.5]])
u, s, vh = np.linalg.svd(H)
w, v = np.linalg.eig(H*H)
```

`np.linalg.eig(H*H)` gives a very different result from this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1417968/673047).

why does that?

Comment: Havn't read those post, but you probably mean `H@H` which is matrix multiplication. `H*H` will be broadcasted multiplication unless `H` is a `np.matrix` type

Comment: Could you summarize the three posts you link to in your question? I feel that would make this question more self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues.  Firstly, you're not transposing the multiplier.  Secondly, you're using elementwise multiplication instead of matrix multiplication.

Here is how you can fix both issues:

```
In [18]: np.linalg.eig(np.matmul(H, H.T))
Out[18]:
(array([1.94501343e+00, 1.14315435e-05, 4.49751401e-02]),
 array([[-0.35979589, -0.82953709,  0.42710084],
        [-0.81600749,  0.05780546, -0.57514373],
        [-0.4524143 ,  0.55545183,  0.69770664]]))
```

Alternatively, you could use `np.matrix` to make the `*` perform matrix multiplication:

```
In [22]: H = np.matrix([[0.1, 0.3, .4],[0.5 , 0.5, 0.9],[0.1, 0.4, 0.5]])

In [23]: np.linalg.eig(H*H.T)
Out[23]:
(array([1.94501343e+00, 1.14315435e-05, 4.49751401e-02]),
 matrix([[-0.35979589, -0.82953709,  0.42710084],
         [-0.81600749,  0.05780546, -0.57514373],
         [-0.4524143 ,  0.55545183,  0.69770664]]))
```

If the matrix contains complex numbers you should be using conjugate transpose (`.H`) instead of transpose (`.T`).  I've chosen to not do this to avoid confusing notation (`H*H.H`).

Comment: thanks for your answer. there are a few elements different from the result in the original post. for instance, the u[2,2] (lower right hand corner) in the original post is 0.55545183 rather than 0.69770664.